# Edit and Save in angular updates the whole list of entities instead of one Angular

Tags: angular

I have a bootstrap for like this

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a type="submit" form="editFormTruck"
              (click)="processForm()"
               class="btn btn-light"
               title="Save Truck"
               data-toggle="tooltip"
               data-placement="bottom">
              <i class="fa fa-save"></i> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Save</span>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="truck">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
    <!--works no forms yet-->
                <form   (ngSubmit)="processForm()"  id="editFormTruck">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label"  ngFor="truckCode">Truck code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="truckCode"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="truck.truckCode">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" ngFor="purchasedDate">purchased Date</label>
                    <input type="text" name="purchaseDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="truck.purchasedDate">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" ngFor="truck.description">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="truck.description">
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

above form belongs to edit component when i click edit from another component where i have a list i come to this component with data inside the input space which is correct but after editing and save all the values in my list changes to the same value that i have edited, this is to say i get this after editing one truck

```
TruckCode   purchasedDate   descriptions    
1   BTY200  2006-05-05  New WOrkdl   Edit  Delete
2   BTY200  2006-05-05  New WOrkdl   Edit  Delete
3   BTY200  2006-05-05  New WOrkdl
```

this is my edit component class

```
export class EditTruckComponent implements OnInit {

  private truck: Truck;

  public truckForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private truckService: TruckService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.truck = this.truckService.getter();
  }

  processForm() {
    if (this.truck.truckId  == undefined) {
      this.truckService.createTruck(this.truck)
        .subscribe((truck) => {
          console.log(truck)
          this.router.navigate([''])
        },(error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      this.truckService.updateTrucks(this.truck)
        .subscribe(
          (truck) => {
            console.log(truck);
            this.router.navigate([''])
          }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }

  }
```

This is the update and creat truck method from the truck component

```
 updateTruck(truck) {
    this.truckService.setter(truck)
    this.router.navigate(['/edits'])
  }

  //this gets us edit page with blank forms.
  newTruck() {
    let truck = new Truck(null, null, new Date(), "")
    this.truckService.setter(truck)
    this.router.navigate(['/edits'])
   }
```

Comment: Can you please also include the updateTrucks method.

Comment: yes i will update now

Comment: @Loke i have updated

Comment: what does `setter` method contai?

Comment: what i did was the set the edit form to contain a truck that already exists , when i click on the edit button from the list of trucks it sets it to that truck so i see it in my form then i should edit

Comment: I guess I would also have to see the truckService.setter method. Most likely that is what is causing you trouble or the way your list is rendered (your *ngFor). Probably unrelated: I'm not sure I understand your use of ngFor in your form. The usual syntax is something like *ngFor="let truck of trucks"

Comment: i changed that ngFor to for = which will be related to id can i send u a git hub link then we communicate ?

Comment: sure. til_ragelse at hotmail com